# Can we give a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, exponential-function, trigonometric-series

Let $a>0$ and $x\in(-1,1)$. Can we give a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}$? Note that the series is convergent. There should be an expression in terms of the cotangent.

My goal is to find a (sharp) upper bound $c(x)$ of the series.

Comment: Have you tried to approximate it with the integral $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+(t+x)^2} dt$? This is equal to a finite value, i.e. $\frac{\pi }{\sqrt a}$

Comment: the series extends to a periodic function, is this perhaps related to a known fourier series of some function...?

Comment: @Crostul Have would this approximation look like?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The series is, up to a constant factor, the density of the wrapped normal distribution $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\mathcal N_{x-k,\:\sigma^2}$ ($a=2\sigma^2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you enjoy special functions
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=\frac{-\psi \left(-x-\sqrt{-a}+1\right)+\psi
   \left(-x+\sqrt{-a}+1\right)-\psi \left(x-\sqrt{-a}\right)+\psi
  \left(x+\sqrt{-a}\right)}{2 \sqrt{-a}}$$
wich can simplify as
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=-\frac{\pi  \left(\cot \left(\pi  \left(\sqrt{-a}-x\right)\right)+\cot \left(\pi 
   \left(\sqrt{-a}+x\right)\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{-a}}$$ and, since $a >0$
$$\color{blue}{\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=\frac{\pi  \left(\coth \left(\pi  \left(\sqrt{a}-i x\right)\right)+\coth \left(\pi 
   \left(\sqrt{a}+i x\right)\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}}$$ what you can simplify using
$$\coth(A+B)+\coth(A-B)=\frac{2 \sin (2 A)}{\cos (2 B)-\cos (2 A)}$$

**Edit**

*In order to keep the results in the answer, I reproduce here what you wrote in comments.*

So, we have finally
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=\frac \pi {\sqrt a}\,\,\frac{\sinh \left(2 \pi  \sqrt{a}\right)}{\cosh \left(2 \pi  \sqrt{a}\right)-\cos(2 \pi  x)}$$ but I think that you cannot make at the same time $a \to 0$ and $x\to \pm 1$ without avoiding $\infty$. In the post, remember that you did precise $x\in(-1,1)$ and not $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d. The digamma function.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can we give a nice upper bound $c(x)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d. First, please, simplify the expression and add the result to the post. We will see later.

Comment: Note that there is a typo in your second displayed equation. The $\pi$ should precede the fraction. (And the same in the third displayed equation.)

Comment: I need to admit that I don't see how we can simplify the series using your identities. Do you've got $$\forall x,y\in\mathbb R:\coth(x+{\rm i}y)+\coth(x-{\rm i}y)=-\frac{2\sinh(2x)}{\cos(2y)-\cosh(2x)}\tag1$$ in mind? This yields $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=-\frac\pi{\sqrt a}\frac{\sinh(2\pi\sqrt a)}{\cos(2\pi x)-\cosh(2\pi\sqrt a)}\tag3.$$ If that's what you've got in mind, how can we proceed for the bound?

Comment: @0xbadf00d   The expression is simple. Do we need a upper bound? What kind of bounds do we need?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Okay, the best bound we can obtain should be $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}=\frac\pi{\sqrt a}\frac{\overbrace{\sinh(2\pi\sqrt a)}^{\ge\:0}}{\underbrace{\cosh(2\pi\sqrt a)}_{>\:1}-\underbrace{\cos(2\pi x)}_{\in[-1,\:1]}}\le\frac\pi{\sqrt a}\frac{\sinh(2\pi\sqrt a)}{\cosh(2\pi\sqrt a)-1}\tag4.$$ Do you agree? That's unfortunate, since this bound tends to $\infty$ as $a\to0+$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty}\frac{1}{a+(x+k)^2} =&\ \frac{1}{a+(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{a+x^2}+\frac{1}{a+(1-x)^2}\\
&+\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{a+(k+(1+x))^2}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{a+(k+(1-x))^2}\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{a+(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{a+x^2}+\frac{1}{a+(1-x)^2}\\
&\ +\int^\infty_0\frac{dk}{a+(k+(1+x))^2}+ \int^\infty_{0} \frac{dk}{a+(k+(1-x))^2}\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{a+(1+x)^2}+\frac{1}{a+x^2}+\frac{1}{a+(1-x)^2}\\
&\ +\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\left(\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{a}}{1+x}\right)+\tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{a}}{1-x}\right)\right)
\end{align}

Comment: How does the first equality follow? Clearly, the series is equal to $\frac1{a+x^2}+\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\frac1{a+(k+x)^2}$.

Comment: By playing around with the indices.

Comment: Yes, trivial. I see.

Comment: Also, you have https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28a%2B%28n%2Bx%29%5E2%29+from+n%3D-infty+to+infty

Comment: Okay, everything is clear to me, but how do we obtain the last inequality?